# (Strong) Duality for the integer programming for $\text{gcd}(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)$

Tags: number-theory, lagrange-multiplier, gcd-and-lcm, duality-theorems, integer-programming

It is known that (quoted from [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), 3rd edition)

> If $a$ and $b$ are any integers, not both zero, then $\text{gcd}(a, b)$ is the smallest positive element of the set $\{ax + by: x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ of linear combinations of $a$ and $b$.

Generally, we can formulate the problem of computing $x = \text{gcd}(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)$ as an integer programming ($P$), as done in [JOTA1977](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00936716):

\begin{align*}
\max & \quad x, \\
\text{subject to } & \quad c_j/x = y_j, \qquad j = 1, 2, \ldots, n, \\
& \quad y_j \in \mathbb{Z}, \qquad j = 1, 2, \ldots, n.
\end{align*}

Its dual ($D$) is given as:

\begin{align*}
\min & \quad \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j z_j, \\
\text{subject to } & \quad \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j z_j > 0, \\
& \quad z_j \in \mathbb{Z}, \qquad j = 1, 2, \ldots, n.
\end{align*}

Then [JOTA1977](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00936716) reads,

> When the $c_j$'s are all integers and $c \neq 0$, it is noted by Greenberg (Ref. 3) that the greatest common divisor of the $c_j$'s is the minimum of $cz$, subject to $cz \ge 1$ and $z$ integer.

I have no access to [Greenberg (Ref. 3)](https://www.elsevier.com/books/integer-programming/greenberg/978-0-12-299450-0).

I have computed the dual of the integer programming above and I got $yz \ge 1$ instead of $cz \ge 1$.

How to obtain the dual of the integer programming for $\text{gcd}$?

---

(***Added 1:*** I compute the dual by the method of Lagrange Multipliers. (I use it in LP, but I am not sure whether this is valid for ILP.) Multiplying $c_j = x y_j$ by $z_i$, summing the $n$ equality constraints, and letting it be an upper bound for $x$: $x \le cz = yzx$.)

(***Added 2:*** I realized that the integer programming above is not linear due to $c_j/x = y_j$.)

Comment: How did *you* compute the dual?

Comment: @MishaLavrov By the method of Lagrange Multipliers. (I use it in LP, but I am not sure whether this is valid for ILP.) Multiplying $c_j = x y_j$ by $z_i$, summing the $n$ equality constraints, and letting it be an upper bound for $x$: $x \le cz = yzx$.

Comment: I'm also having trouble getting Lagrange duality to work. Are you sure that "Greenberg (Ref. 3)" does use duality to prove this fact?

Comment: About whether Lagrange multipliers are valid for IP: in general, the dual is the same for the IP and for its fractional relaxation (e.g. for an ILP and its LP relaxation), so unless your IP formulation is perfect there will be a duality gap. In particular, the relaxation of your IP is unbounded, so we don't expect things to work without fiddling.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I have no access to Greenberg (Ref. 3), and I am not sure whether it uses Lagrange duality. However, in the abstract of JOTA1977, it is mentioned that "The primal-dual formulation (in this paper) is based on a number-theoretic, rather than a Lagrangian, duality property; consequently, it avoids the duality gap common to Lagrangian duals in integer programming." By the way, I have edited the post to include the dual program given in the JOTA1977 paper.

Comment: Looking over the Meyer and Fleisher paper (1) it doesn't claim that Greenberg uses duality at all, so I assume that they are just citing a description of the Euclidean algorithm, and (2) they prove strong duality right there in Theorem 2.1, and doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks. So I have probably misunderstood the citation to Greenberg (Ref. 3). Now I have a better understanding of this JOTA1977 paper and I am satisfied with Theorem 2.1. (If you like, you can convert your valuable comments into an answer and I will accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Converting Misha Lavrov's help comment into an answer:*

Looking over the Meyer and Fleisher paper (1) it doesn't claim that Greenberg uses duality at all, so I assume that they are just citing a description of the Euclidean algorithm, and (2) they prove strong duality right there in Theorem 2.1.